# SPSS Looping across multiple string variables to find duplicates

Tags: string, loops, spss

I have a long list of records with text names in two columns, x1 and x2. I want to compare x2 names with x1 names and identify those that match any instance of x1 and note it in temp variable.  I've tried looping through the two columns (see syntax below) but I get a "y" at every record.

I hope someone can show me the correct syntax.

Thanks

Bren

```
string temp(a1).
compute temp= "n".
vector x=x1 to x2.
loop #i=1 TO 77700.
loop #j = (#i+1) to 77700.
if x(#i)=x(#j) temp = "y".
end loop.
end loop.
execute.
```

Comment: I removed the sample data, it didn't show in the table format.

Comment: Is every name in x2 unique?

Comment: Mirirai, I'm hoping the following will clarify. The names in x1 are in the long format with the same name for 5 possible x2 names.x1 x2 temp
Greg Smith Allen Anderson n
Greg Smith Jack Lovin y
Tom Watson Henry Jones n
Ellen Hampton Jack Lovin y
Jack Lovin Fred Dover y
Jack Lovin Alice Wanders n
Jack Lovin Patrick Evans n
Jack Lovin Thomas Smith n
Fred Dover Kelly Bunson n

Comment: A more direct answer would be no, the names in x2 would not necessarily be unique. Sorry if this isn't as clear as I would like it to be.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I solved the problem.

```
COMPUTE index=$CASENUM.
SORT CASES BY name1.
STRING key (a63).
COMPUTE main=name2.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE * / BREAK name1 / found=N.
RENAME VARIABLES name1=main.
MATCH FILES FILE index / TABLE * /IN=match / BY main .
SORT CASES BY index.
```

Thanks for those that viewed and were thinking about the problem for me.

Comment: Yepp, this looks like a good solution to me. However, I like to add some ideas/advice for the syntax. 1) Using the *-Operator in the Aggregate Outfile command will likely overwrite your original data set, and then the syntax fails. 2) You don't need to copy "name2" into "main" or rename "name1" into "main". Instead you can in "MATCH FILES" for "TABLE *" just use the subcommand /RENAME (name1 = name2) . In this case you would match by the variable "name2" of course.